# Unamaged code leaks memory when invoked via IIS and not via a console app

Tags: c#, c, wcf, iis, memory-leaks

I have an unmanaged library written in C ( which also uses Intel MKL libraries internally ) which is used in a WCF web service. Straight up PInvoke is used to call the exposed methods and the the library calls return a pointer to a double array which is copied over to a managed array in C# before calling free() on the pointer.

```
        double* xStars = null;
        metaData meta = new metaData();
        double[] output = null;
        bool hasError;
        string errorMessage;
        try
        {
            int errCode = someCFunction(...some params...
                &xStars,
                &meta);

            output = new double[meta.ArrayLength];
            for (int j = 0; j < meta.ArrayLength; j++)
            {
                output[j] = (xStars[j]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteToEventLog();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
                            //Also in the C library
                            //Calls free(void *) 
            freeDoubleArray(&xStars);
            freeMeta(&meta);
        }
```

I have test suites that can either invoke this via

- IIS as a web service call or
- Console app which runs all the other business logic but does not operate as a WS
- A smaller console application which just exercises the class which does the PInvoke
- When run via the console app (2), the start up memory used is ~50MB and remains pretty much stable even after the underlying C code is invoked several 100 times in a loop
- When run via console app (2), start up memory is even smaller, about 24MB and remains stable after several 100 calls
- When run via IIS, even at service start-up, the memory usage is around 150-200 MB and keeps increasing fir each call to the C library. It finally gets to a point where IIS recycles it because the memory being used exceeds the limits set

What's wrong with the way it's being used in IIS? Console app (2) is basically all of the code but just run as a standalone application rather than a web service. That being the case, the application does not exhibit any memory leaks or excessive usage.

The things I did so far to understand the root cause :

1. Used Performance Monitor to profile for Private Bytes and GC bytes in all heaps. Managed memory usage climbs on process start and remains pretty much a flat line throughout the test while private bytes used spikes to a couple of 100 MB on the first call and keeps increasing slightly for each iteration of the test.
2. Used Debug Diag to profile for unmanaged memory leaks and of the 500 MB used by the IIS worker process, Debug diag indicates that the C library has about 43 MB of unreleased memory which it thinks is a leak but does not explain where the rest are being used
3. I used the ANTS Memory profiler and it indicated that a major chunk of the memory was unmanaged and managed memory usage was at worst, within 30 MB.

I guess I don't have enough rep points to post a picture or I couldve posted the screen shot of Performance Monitor. The person who wrote the C code thinks that this is an IIS issue ( or something to do with the web service C# code ) and points out that when used in a standalone app, there aren't any apparent leaks. The debugging tools I used seem to indicate otherwise.

Any suggestions on what I could do next to pinpoint where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

If ANTS Memory profiler has identified that a "major chunk" of memory was allocated to unmanaged code where you expected no unmanaged memory usage, then that would be a good place to start investigations.

What happens if you uncomment "freeDoubleArray(&xStars);" and "freeMeta(&meta);"? Do you get similar behavior in your console application as you did with your ISS web service?

What happens if you force a GC collection at the end of your finally block? Does your ISS web service then behave in a similar way to your console application?